# Pause renovatebot for single PR

Tags: continuous-integration

We have configured renovate for few of our repositories. It generates PRs after approval via dependency dashboard and automerges patch releases.

But there is one update which fails the CI - it look like there is an error in the library itself. While we continue to work on the master branch renovate rebases it's update branches which again triggers the CI.

Can I pause renovate to work on that single PR without closing it until we have have fixed this dependency so that it dos not start the CI  over and over? (It will fail anyway)

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration option named `stopUpdatingLabel`. With this feature one can add a label to the pr to stop renovate from updating it like so:

```json
{
  "stopUpdatingLabel": "take-a-break-renovate"
}
```

The feature is enabled by default and listens on the label `stop-updating`.

It's documented over here:
https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#stopupdatinglabel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could resolve this by pinning the version of the problem library temporarily so it doesn't update it to the "erroring version"?

You could use the `packageRules` [configuration](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/) to set the allowed version to the known good one, preventing the problematic update.

```json
"packageRules": [
  {
    "matchPackageNames": ["@angular/router"],
    "allowedVersions": "<15.0.0"
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, indeed a nice workaround but I want to work more stateless, without editing any config. Preferred ways would be to write a comment, change the title or add a specific label to the pr

Comment: Another way, if you want to change the config concerning that, would be the "ignoreDeps" option.